# How to create binary variable from variables having characters and numbers?

Tags: r, indexing, dataset, binary-data

My data is as below:

```
ID var1 var2  
1    A    2 
2    5    6
3    B    3
4    7    D
5    1    1
6    2    5
7    6    Y
8    7    G
9    8    C
```

Value of Var1 and Var 2 are one of 1~9,A~Z. I want to make binary data set like this.
New value = 1 if value from original is 4-9 and new value = 0 otherwise.

How I can make binary index from above data?

Comment: Can you show your expected output too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to include both var1 and var2. You can use `grepl` which return TRUE or FALSE. I called that data frame df. `|` is `or` so that a TRUE is returned if 4-9 is in var1 or var2.

```
df$New <- as.numeric((grepl("[4-9]", df$var1)) | (grepl("[4-9]", df$var2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `%in%` operator to check if each value in your column is in a target set:

```
as.numeric(dat$var1 %in% 4:9)
# [1] 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1
as.numeric(dat$var2 %in% 4:9)
# [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Even though you have character data there's no need to use string functions like `grep` -- in R `"4" == 4` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: The original variable is unlikely to be numeric given that it is a mix of letters and numbers.

Comment: @Thomas this code works fine for factor or character data. Check out `"8" == 8` and `factor("8") == 8`.

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(as.character(interaction(dat[,-1])),"[4-9]")+0
#[1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
```